# Prove if $A$ is hermitian and $A^m=I$, then $A^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove If $A_{n\times n}$ is hermitian over $\mathbb C$ and $A^m=I, m\in \mathbb N$, then $A^2=I$

In other words, we need to show that $A$ is unitary, since its hermitian $A=A^*$, then $A^2=A^*A=AA^*=I$.

I don't know how to tackle this though, maybe somehow use that the polynomial $x^m-1$ annihilate $A$ and both it and $x^2-1$ and have a common root?

Comment: The eigen-value of a hermitian matrix are real.

Comment: The property $\exists m\in \mathbb N\left(A^m=I_n\right)$ implies that $A$ is diagonalizable and all eigenvalues are roots of the unity. It being hermitian implies its eigenvalues are real. So $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix whose entries are what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine that:

- The matrix is diagonalizable. [Hermitian Matrices are Diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363421/hermitian-matrices-are-diagonalizable)
- The eigenvalues satisfy $\lambda^m = 1$.
- The eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are real.

To get that the matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix with entries $\pm 1$, for which the claim holds, and your result follows directly.

---

Or, closer to your attempt. The minimal polynomial $P$ of $A$ divides $X^m -1 =\prod_{j= 0}^{m-1} (X - \zeta^j)$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity. And the roots of $P$  are the eigenvalues of $A$. These eigenvalues are all real (as $A$ is hermitian). Yet the only real roots of $X^m -1$ are $1$, and possibly $-1$ (depending on the parity of $m$). Therefore $P$ divides $ (X-1)(X+1)= X^2 -1$ and $A^2 - I= 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

1. What can you say about eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix?
2. What can you say about eigenvalues of a matrix if $x^m-1$ annihilates it?
3. Relate 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3):

Using the spectral decomposition theorem, there exists a unitary matrix $U \in M_n(\Bbb C)$, such that:

$$U^* A U = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n) \ \ \ \ (\star)$$

With $\lambda_i$'s being the eigenvalues of $A$. Raising both sides to the $m$th power, then comparing, we obtain: $\lambda_i ^m = 1$, for all $i$.

However, we know that the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are real. So, for all $i$, we have $\lambda_i ^2 = 1$. Going back to $(\star)$, we get the result.

Answer (score 2):

We can play an [old trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/768586) that does not require the use of eigenvalues or diagonalisation. Suppose $A$ is Hermitian and $A^m=I$ for some natural number $m$.

When $m=2k$, let $x$ be an arbitrary vector and $y=(A^2-I)x$. Then
\begin{align}
0 &= x^\ast(A^m-I)y\\
&=x^\ast(A^2-I)\left[(A^2)^{k-1} + (A^2)^{k-2} + \cdots + (A^2) + I\right]y\\
&=y^\ast\left[(A^2)^{k-1} + (A^2)^{k-2} + \cdots + (A^2) + I\right]y\\
&=\|A^{k-1}y\|^2 + \|A^{k-2}y\|^2 + \cdots + \|Ay\|^2 + \|y\|^2\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm. Now, what does $(1)$ tell you?

If $m=2k+1$ instead, let $y=(A-I)x$. Then
\begin{align}
0 &= x^\ast(A^m-I)y\\
&=x^\ast(A-I)\left(A^{2k} + A^{2k-1} + \cdots + A + I\right)y\\
&=y^\ast\left(A^{2k} + A^{2k-1} + \cdots + A + I\right)y\\
&=y^\ast\left(\sum_{j=0}^kA^{2j} + \sum_{j=1}^k A^{2j-1}\right)y\\
&=y^\ast\left(\sum_{j=0}^kA^{2j} + \sum_{j=1}^k A^{2j+2k}\right)y.
\end{align}
In this case, can you prove something stronger?